# angular 6 router navigation not working

Tags: angular, angular6

I have migrated my angular application from angular 5 to 6,
when  I am calling router navigation,

```
   this.router.navigate(['doctor-log-in']).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      }, function (err) {
        console.log('in errrrr');
        console.log(err);
        });
```

**it's giving Below Error**

> main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'OVERWRITE' of undefined
>       at new n (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at n.applyServerOverwrite (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at n.updateInfo_ (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at new n (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at n.createRepo (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at n.databaseFromApp (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at Object.e.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at n._getService (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)
>       at n.u.(anonymous function) [as database] (http://localhost:4200/main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1:954493)
>       at new n (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1)

Comment: Please provide more information, such as your package.json content.